# format date returns wrong result

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I use an autofilter macro to get values from today - 3 months, but while the result seems to be correct, the formatted date is shown wrong:

```
Sub LastThreeMonths()

    Dim strDateFirst As String
    Dim strDateLast As String
    Dim strMonthNow As String
  
    strMonthNow = Month(Now)

    strDateFirst = (strMonthNow - 3) & "/" & "1" & "/" & frmEntry.cboYear.Value
    strDateLast = strMonthNow & "/" & LastDay(CDate(strMonthNow)) & "/" & frmEntry.cboYear.Value

    
    MsgBox Format(strDateFirst, "dd-mm-yyyy") & vbCrLf & Format(strDateLast, "dd-mm-yyyy")



End Sub
```

The Debug.Print returns this for `strDateFirst` 07-01-2022 and this for `strDateLast` 30-10-2022
It should be "01-07-2022" for the `strDateFirst` variable.

The filter works correctly though.

What am i missing? I guess it has something to do with the subtraction of "3" from the current month.

Comment: Change the order of `(strMonthNow - 3) & "/" & "1"` to `"1" & "/" & (strMonthNow - 3) `.

Comment: But the order for the autofilter date to work is the american date format: mm/dd/yyyy. If i would change it to dd/mm/yyyy, wouldnt i get an error? Also, it works for the other variable ```strDateLast```

Comment: *What am i missing?* You use incorrect datatypes for variables. Use those datatypes which matches the stored values (Date for first 2 variables and Integer for last one). And use general, not national, VBA date format while processing the data. Also - `strMonthNow` stores a number as string, you call `CDate(strMonthNow)` (for example, `CDate("10")`) - and what do you want to receive with this expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the correct type declarations and use DateSerial to set the date:

```
Sub LastThreeMonths()
    Dim DateFirst As Date
    Dim DateLast As Date

    DateFirst = DateSerial(frmEntry.cboYear.Value, Month(Now) - 3, 1)
    DateLast = DateSerial(frmEntry.cboYear.Value, Month(Now) + 1, 0)

    MsgBox Format(DateFirst, "dd-mm-yyyy") & vbCrLf & Format(DateLast, "dd-mm-yyyy")
End Sub
```

By setting the day as `0` in the `Month(Now) + 1` will return the last day of the current month.

[image]